# How to upload a PDF File to firebase that is already in memory

Tags: swift, firebase, upload, firebase-storage

I have seen posts and read the docs on how to upload a file with a url reference to local disk, however, I cannot find anything about how to do this with a file in memory?  The file is an array of pdfs.  I take it I have to have some kind of URL reference to that file.  Where would I URL reference a pdf in memory?  Anybody know?

Edit:

I used this code from the Docs, however, I'm getting the following error for putData: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
Which I think means the constructor is not expecting a type of PDFDoc?

```
@IBAction func confirmUploadButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let uuid = UUID().uuidString
        // Create a root reference
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        
        // Create a storage reference from our storage service
        let storageRef = storage.reference()
        
        // Data in memory
        let data = Data()

        // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
        let pdfRef = storageRef.child("docRequest/" + uuid + "/" + ".pdf")

        // Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
        let uploadTask = pdfRef.putData(pdfDocument, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
          guard let metadata = metadata else {
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            print(error)
            return
          }
          // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type.
          let size = metadata.size
          // You can also access to download URL after upload.
          pdfRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            guard let downloadURL = url else {
              // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                print(error)
              return
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Save the PDF file to upload to your sandbox folder at first.

Comment: @ElTomato the user may be uploading as many as 20 pdfs at a time so I don't want to save all that to their phone.  I need to to this in memory.  I'm not finding anything on people having to convert pdfs to data object however.

Comment: No. 1, you have never said you are uploading as many as 20 PDF files.  You have only said 'a file'.  No. 2, if you are going to upload as many as 20 PDF files, so what?  Save them all as an array.

Comment: @ElTomato Well its one pdf at a time and no I'm not having problems with that.  As stated above in the question and also in the comment the question is how to convert from pdf to data object.  And we can safely say my requirements are not to save to disk.

Comment: After pulling my hair out for a while found out how to convert the file.  Post up in here if anybody needs it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the data for the PDF in memory already, you can upload that data to Firebase Storage by calling `putData`. See for an example the documentation on [Upload from data in memory](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_data_in_memory), or this [code in the Firebase quickstart project](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/storage/StorageExampleSwift/ViewController.swift#L98-L113).

Comment: Do I need to do some kind of conversion to NSData for a PDF doc to get this to work?

Comment: I have no idea what your current `pdfDocument` variable is, but you'll need to get the bytes of the PDF into the NSData: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata

Answer (score 1):

This line is the issue

```
let pdfRef = storageRef.child("docRequest/" + uuid + "/" + ".pdf")
```

because it will create a path of

```
docRequest/xxxxx/.pdf
```

So you should use this

```
let pdfRef = storageRef.child("docRequest/" + uuid + ".pdf")
```

when will be a path of

```
docRequest/xxxxx.pdf
```

Also, please ensure that when that file is written to storage, you also save the url in Firebase so you can get to it later.

As far as a PDF in memory, the PDFKit (which I think you're using) has functions to work with that, check into pdfData(actions:) renderer to produce a Data object